# Config Mgt Tech Stack Support with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to Ansible and I have some specific queries:

1. Application/Web Serves Run-time Snapshot & Drift : Do we have out of the box Ansible playbooks which can create Application Server level Snapshot, For example a WAS ND Snapshot will be having details like JVM, JDBC, JMS, Shared Lib, Virtual Hosts in a XML format or some other format and Drift here means the difference between two snapshot take in two different times and a detailed report on the difference and similarities. What I would also like to know is if Ansible Tower can give detailed View of each Application/Web Server configuration in detail for each environment? I am looking for products like WAS ND, WLS, Tomcat, WildFly/Jboss, WAS CE, IHS, IIS, OHS
2. Application/Web Server Run-time Configurations update: Here Runtime configuration update means, suppose I want to update only a JMS topic or create a new Shared Library on an existing WAS ND instance as part of a release. Do we have out of the box Ansible playbooks which can do this?
3. I would like to know if there are out of the box Ansible playbooks which can do Run Time Configuration Snapshot/Drift & Run time Configuration deployment/updates for following products :

Messaging : TIBCO EMS, WMQ, Rabbit MQ, Active MQ, TIBCO BE, TIBCO BW
BPM : AMX BPM, Oracle BPM, TIBCO BPM

4. Does Ansible have integration with the following:
   PaaS : PCF, Red Hat Open Shift integration?
5. Environment Replication/Migration : Does Ansible Tower have the feature to replicate or migrate an existing environment of any given Tech stack or combination to a new environment? For example: migrating a WAS ND environment having 2 clusters, 4 nodes and 20 JVMs to a PROD environment of 4 clusters, 10 Nodes, 100 JVMs, this goes for other tech stacks[Web Servers/Messaging/BPM etc] as well that I have mentioned above.
6. Environment Comparison in Detail : Does Ansible Tower have the feature to compare two environment of any given Tech stack? For example: comparing a UAT WAS ND with a PROD WAS ND environment, this goes for other tech stacks[Web Servers/Messaging/BPM etc] as well that I have mentioned above.
7. Searching Configurations : Does Ansible Tower have the feature to search configurations in multiple environment(s) of any given Tech stack? For example: searching a Java EE applications JDBC data source value in its DEV, UAT and PROD WAS ND environments, this goes for other tech stacks[Web Servers/Messaging/BPM etc] as well that I have mentioned above.

I would really appreciate if anybody could give me more details on my above queries.

Answer (score 1):

From the questions you are asking it sounds like you haven't bothered to actually read any of the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/) that's readily available nor have you bothered to try installing and testing Ansible. In a nutshell, no Ansible does not come with any predefined playbooks nor does Ansible Tower come with any predefined features like the ones you listed.

Ansible is a configuration management and orchestration platform, much like Puppet, Chef, CFEngine, and others.  They are tools that you need to use to write your own custom definitions for.  You can write Ansible playbooks, puppet recipes, etc. to do much of what you asked, but it's entirely up to you to write your own custom tasks.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for you quick response really appreciate the effort. Yes I only went through few Ansible videos in Youtube . But I have spent some time with Chef . I am developing a project for end to end configuration management for the tech stacks  I mentioned and I  also consulted with Chef architects but they don't have any out of box cookbooks/recipes to cater these features, also Chef console/UI is has very limited features, this is the reason I was trying to see if Ansible tower can cater the features like search/compare/deploy/replicate configurations of all the tech stacks.